# Natural Language Understanding - Analyze

Tags: watson-nlu

`NLU` (Natural Language Understanding) Analyze call is failing with the error codes below,

```
{"error": "cannot analyze: downstream issue", "code": 500 }
{"error": "failure to communicate with server", "code": 500 }
{"error": "requested service timeout", "code": 500 }
```

This started happening since 09-Oct-2017.
It is working sometimes and failing most of the times.
Is there any change deployed for NLU?

Answer (score 0):

Is it happening consistently with a given set of inputs? I would suggesting contacting the bluemix support at https://support.ng.bluemix.net/supportticket/?app=technicalsupport&index=13 to follow-up on the issue.

In general, code 500's are unexpected and require some level of digging for the support team to triage.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is not happening always. I have raised a support ticket.

Comment: Currently I am facing the same problems... @Sukanto Do you have any additional information from the support team? Thanks